ConTeXt - how to make a cloze test compatible with \starttyping...\stoptyping
I have written an environment for cloze test worksheets as follow :
\def\AnswerLines#1#2{
    \startmode[solution] \blank\hrule\blank\color[darkblue]{#1} \stopmode   
    \startnotmode[solution] 
        \thinrules[color=darkgray, interlinespace=big, n=#2]
    \stopnotmode
    }

It works fine with text and math, itemize structures...
for example, this code works fine
\enablemode[solution] % this line can be commented
\starttext
My question which should be answered in 5 or 6 lines of code.
\AnswerLines{
    a solution
    \startitemize \dorecurse{3}{\item random stuff} \stopitemize
    }{7}
\stoptext

... but it fails with code in a \starttyping ... \stoptyping structure (or in \startPY...\stopPY with t-vim module)
for example, the code below won't compile
\enablemode[solution] % this line can be commented to disable mode
\starttext
My question which should be answered in 5 or 6 lines of code.
\AnswerLines{
    a solution
    \starttyping
        some code
    \stoptyping
    }{7}
\stoptext

the error is
tex error       > runaway error: end of file encountered
mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 1
> exit status: 256

The code used to work with an old version of ConTeXt Mkiv, but I don't know how to fix it for LMTX.
Question : How can I fix my code to allow answers with code ?

Not by computer, but does it work if you put the code into a buffer (\startbuffer ... code \stopbuffer) and then call it inside with \getbuffer?

Thank you for your answer, which helps a lot. I will write an answer below. If there is a way to avoid buffers it would be great.

With the help of mickep (thanks a lot), I have a first solution with buffers.
\usemodule[vim] 
\definevimtyping[PY]
    [syntax=python,
    escape=on
    margin=0.2cm,
    ]

\enablemode[solution] % this line can be commented
\starttext
My question which should be answered in 5 or 6 lines of code.
\AnswerLines{
    a solution
\startitemize \dorecurse{3}{\item random stuff} \stopitemize
    }{7}

    \enablemode[solution] % this line can be commented to disable mode
    \starttext
    My question which should be answered in 5 or 6 lines of code.
    \startbuffer[code1]
        my random code
    \stopbuffer
    \startbuffer[code2]
        \startPY
        my other random code with python highlight
        \stopPY
    \stopbuffer
    
    \AnswerLines{    
        a solution
        \typebuffer[code1] 
        \getbuffer[code2]
        }{7}
    \stoptext

It works. If someone has a way to keep the code in the text (the same order as in the output) il would be great.
